# Representing array elements on a square in Python (as image)

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `A` with shape `(3,3)`. Is there a way to represent the array elements on a square of size 3x3? In general, I would like to represent `nxn` arrays on a square of size `nxn`? The expected output is attached.

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[10,20,30],[40,50,60],[70,80,90]])
```

The expected output is:

[image: Output]

Comment: Just `print(A)`?

Comment: Do you want an image or text?

Comment: I want an image with array elements mentioned in the above format.

Comment: If you want an image you can go with [matplotlib annotated heatmaps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) that has a nice API:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

A = np.array([[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]])

ax = sns.heatmap(A,
            annot=True, square=True, cbar=False,
            xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False,
            cmap=ListedColormap(['white']),
            linecolor='k', lw=2,
            annot_kws={'size': 30}
           )

ax.figure.savefig('img.png')
```

output:

[image]